# сделать uppercase str3 если у него имеется str1

Tags: python

str1 = "hello"

str3 = "friendhelloworldmy"

output: friendHELLOworldmy

Answer (score 2):

```
str1 = "hello"
str3 = "friendhelloworldmy"

print(str3.replace (str1, str1.upper()))
```

**stdout:**

```
friendHELLOworldmy
```